# Unable to access ENV variables after updating to Node v18

Tags: javascript, node.js, vite

I am working on a web application that was built using HTML/CSS/Javascript and Vite.js.  I wanted to update Vite from v2 to the latest version (v4), and in order to do so, I also needed to update Node.js from v15 to the latest v18 ([docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project)).

I updated both Vite and Node, and everything seemed to be going well until I noticed I was no longer able to access ENV variables. I don't understand what the problem could be as I haven't changed anything in the actual files, and there are no error messages in the console (other than showing variables as returning undefined when I try to access them).

For example, I store the URL for API calls to a private server in an ENV file, and then access it from my `main.js` file like so:

Main.js

```
// Define base_url for API calls to server
export const endpoint_base_url = import.meta.env.VITE_ENDPOINT_BASE_URL;

console.log(endpoint_base_url) // Returns undefined after updating
```

My DOTENV file looks like this:

```
VITE_ENDPOINT_BASE_URL = (private URL goes here)
```

I'm thinking that Node.js update is the problem -- As soon as I update Node, the ENV variables stop working, even if I'm still on the older version of Vite. Here is the [changelog](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V18.md#18.16.0) for the version I'm updating to (18.6.0).

That being said, I've also read through the Vite migration guides for both v3 and v4. There is [one section about ENV variables](https://vitejs.dev/guide/migration.html#environment-variables), but it doesn't seem like it applies to my issue.  Still, in case it's relevant, here is the [migration guide from v2 to v3](https://vitejs.dev/guide/migration.html#migration-from-v3), and here is the [migration guide from v3 to v4](https://v3.vitejs.dev/guide/migration.html).  And here is the section about ENV variables in the [Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html).

Maybe I need to configure dotenv differently somehow? Or change the import statement in main.js? I'm fairly stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE** I tried moving the ENV files into the folder that contains all the HTML/JS/CSS files, even though it's not the project root. That worked. So now I'm still confused, but at least I have a working app!

File structure:

```
--> Root folder
----->www-vite
-------->Pages, index.html, ENV files, package.json, etc.
```